# multiple parents multiple child relationships

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table which looks like below:

```
Parent   Child
--------------
10       100
10       101
20       101
20       102
```

Now when I query for parent 10 I should get the below answer:

```
Result1:
--------
10
100
101
20
```

The parent 10 has childs 100 and 101. since 101 is a common child for 10 & 20 the result should also contain parent 20.

Now when I query for parent 20 I should get the below answer:

```
Result2:
--------
20
101
102
10
```

The parent 20 has childs 101 and 102. since 101 is a common child for 10 & 20 the result should also contain parent 10.

Now when I query for child 101 I should get the below answer:

```
Result3:
--------
101
20
10
```

The child 101 has parents 10 and 20. since 101 is a common child for 10 & 20 the result should also contain parent 10 and Parent 20.

Is it possible to get this in one query? If not how can we do it?